# DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC 3 WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a WebGrid that I'm creating and I want a dropdownlist in there - I can't find a way to make one of the rows a DropDownList - any tutorials out there?

Right now i've been trying to use the "format:" setting to set it up - but I keep getting errors

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your model includes something like this:

```
public SelectList Countries { get; set; }
```

in the Metadatatype for your class and your controller populates the list, you can then call the DropDownList inside the webgrid:

```
myGrid.Column(header: "", format: @<text> @Html.DropDownList("Countries")</text>),
```

After finding the answer, it is obvious; but I was tearing my hair a few minutes ago.

Hope this helps someone keep his/her hair.

Comment: What does it do to put a select list in the header?  Are you using it for filtering?

Comment: What about getting selected values how can we reach and get the id of that row ?